# Chrome on Android won't load my page

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

My site http://terminal.jcubic.pl won't load on my new Android phone, there is progress (blue progress bar below address) in one place and it hangs, I can stop the tab or open new tab, so it's not infinite loop, but the page is not responding.On my old phone (Android 2.3) the page is loading but there is no terminal, when I nload just the terminal using http://terminal.jcubic.pl/android.html it loads and terminal is working, same page don't load in google chrome on android 6.

The page and library work fine in Chrome on Desktop and other browsers.

How can I find the reason why, I think it's because of the library because api reference page that don't create instance of terminal is working fine.

How can I debug this? Any idea, why the page is not working, will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect your phone to a computer, and do remote debugging

```
 https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/
```

Look for the network activity. 
Questions to answer:

- Are js files not downloaded ? others ?
- what headers are sent ?
- same that with older device ?

Comment: and is js enabled ? :D  kidding

Comment: After I've posted, I've remind that there was something like remote debugging in chrome and I've found the same link, will try it.